# How to simulate iPhone 5 in Titanium Studio?

Tags: titanium

I am trying to run the iPhone emulator to emulate iPhone 5.
I ran the application Run as > iPhone Simulator and tried to change the device as shown below

[image: Configuring iPhone simulator to simulate iPhone 5 in Titanium Studio]

But when i run the simulator it still shows iPhone 4 simulator, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer..

For some reason, we could not set the `Hardware > Device` to iPhone(Retina 4-inch)
when running from Titanium Studio.

You create a new sample project in XCode and run the emulator from there and select
`iPhone(Retina 4-inch)` from `Hardware > Device` menu when the emulator shows up.

Close the emulator and run the iPhone simulator from Titanium Studio, now you will be
seeing iPhone 5 simulator.

Answer (score 3):

You should change the run configuration of Simulator.

[image: 1.Click the run configurations]

[image: 2.Change the display type to 'Retina & Tall']

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the iPhone simulator outside of titanium. There is not need for an application to use, just open the simulator.

The simulator can be found here:

```
Applications > xCode (show package contents) > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhone Simulator > Developer > Applications > iOS Simulator.
```

Open this application, and select the hardware of choosing through `Hardware > Device`

After that, close the simulator, and launch the app through Titanium as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Just open xcode (Welocome screen is enough, no need for empty project). Then in main menu open: **Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator**
Then in simulator open in main menu: **Hardware > Device > ...select device...**
Go back to Titanium Studio and run application again.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to go to "Run Configurations" in Titanium Studio and then change "Display Type" to Retina.